# How to create a component with nested Selectors in Angular2

Tags: angular

Iam new to angular2, I am trying to build a component with nested selectors. how can I build a component like that. if my question is not clear please see below i need to build a component that can be used like this. Is there any method or approach i can follow. Please help

```
 <parent [width]='100'>
        <child [title]='hi'></child>
        <child [title]='hello'></child>
 </parent>
```

Comment: I can't derive from the code what "use like this" means. I also don't know what you mean with nested selectors.

Comment: I think you just want simple parent-children structure. You need to make parent and children separately. Then use <ng-content> in parent and just use components in template like in code you provided.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i dont know what to name this, i need to create a custom grid which can be defined like the code snippet i have added

Comment: @jmachnik i should be able to recognise the child selectors used inside parent and read the inputs

Comment: Read the inputs of child components?

Comment: @jmachnik if possible yes.

Comment: i know this may appear pretty stupid for you people , iam sorry please bear :D

Comment: @AmarnathRShenoy read this carefully: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: I think you should check out the other tutorials at angular.io as well ;-)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer like you wondered earlier i still dont know what to call this stuff and what should i search for . Nested selector is the only keyword i have now :-( and no one other than me will understand it :D

Comment: Are you trying to make a component that will be rendered ONLY in this structure?

Comment: What about expressing what behavior result you expect?

Answer (score 0):

As jmachnik stated, using`<ng-content>` in the parent template is the easiest way to nest unrelated components. Angular2 *purposely* does not support parent child selectors.

```
// Does not work
@Component({
   selector:  'parent child',
   ...
})
```

If you need something like this, then utilizing the @ViewChildren or @ContentChildren property annotations in the parent class will give you the references to the child components.

I'll refer you to the [angular api](http://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

You can mention the child selectors in the template of parent and import the child components in to Parent

```
import { Component,Input } from "@angular/core";
import {childSelector} from 'pathname for childselector file'
@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: `
<childselector1></childselector1>
<childselector2></childselector2>
`
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```